# How to migrate Profiles from Developer edition to Enterprise edition?

Tags: salesforce

We are facing an issues while migrating Profiles from Developer edition to Enterprise edition. Profiles will be created but the Namespace prefix will not be carried when tried to move profiles using Eclipse and ANT. Profiles are not migrated by using Packaging. If any one of you has faced the same issue and came across with some solution for this please reply for this post.

Answer (score 0):

Only one managed package will be availabe in developer edition .Managed packages will not be supported in other editions . name space prefix will not be available in other editions.So this might be cause of the problem.
And few more points I would like to mention here :
         You cannot migrate profiles directly in any instance. You will need to migrate complete Custom Objects, Pages, Recordtypes, Page Layouts etc then only profile will be migrated.
Profiles have a lot of information in them and they depend on other objects being in the destination org when they are deployed. If the deployment can be broken up in pieces, this can be a way to simplify the process. Custom objects and new fields can be pushed first as they do not depend on anything. Then the code and Visualforce pages along with validation rules, workflow and approvals can be pushed. Finally profiles can be pushed now that all of the dependent object for a profile are in place. Expect the pushing of the profiles to be a tricky process. In some cases a profile may even need to be created manually from scratch

Regards,

Naveen

SSE , Salesforce CI expert group

http://www.autorabit.com